# Mobile browser: wrapper shifts elements to the left creating a white space on the right

Tags: css

I have elements contained within a wrapper that is 1174px wide. However, when I view the site on a mobile browser, the elements behind the wrapper get pushed to the left creating a white space on the right.

I am not sure why this is happening as 1174px is the width of the widest element (`#slide`). If some elements were different widths, I'd understand, but that is not the case so I am clueless at this point. Can somebody help me figure out where I went wrong?

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile or some other mobile framework of just plain CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I added this to the head and it worked like a charm.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1174">`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the width of different elements in your site. eg(header, nav, etc). It may vary.

iPhone takes the maximum width. and it leaves the extra space blank.

please use one & same width or use a wrapper and put everything in it.

Comment: Everything outside of the wrapper is 100% width. The wrapper itself is 1174px wide which is the width of the widest element (`#slide`). Is this what you mean, or do you mean something else?